# How do I center several views in an Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my case I have two text views, I want them to be centered in my activity.

The problem is when I use:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

The two text views are above each other and I'm using `LinearLayout` as a parent.

Comment: Could you post your complete XML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the vertical and parent-based parts, and leave just the

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

for both of the `TextViews`.

If it's enough, that the first TextView is centered vertically, then you can set it to `|center_vertical`, and bind the second to this one with `android:layout_below`.

If you need these text views to be exactly in the vertical center of the activity, then you should encapsulate them into an other (e.g. Linear)Layout with `android:height="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` (in `RelativeLayout`) or `android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"`.

Comment: thank you it worked!
this is result:
`<TextView 
 android:layout_gravity="center" 
 android:id="@+id/firstTextView" 
 android:text="@+id/firstTextView" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true">
</TextView>
  
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
 android:text="@+id/secondTextView"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
 android:layout_below="@+id/firstTextView">
</TextView>`

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"` is only valid for a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Orientation property of the LinearLayout to "Horizontal":

```
<LinearLayout blah blah android:orientation="Horizontal"></LinearLayout>
```

> **Note** : This tells the LinearLayout how you want the elements to stack, if
>   you dont define this, then it will not
>   stack them properly, refer to my
>   diagram below for an explanation.

When you set this property it will have the elements be right next to eachother.

**Horizontal**

[x][x]

**Vertical**

[x]

[x]

Another thing to keep in mind is that all you should need to do to center elements in a linear layout is this:

```
<LinearLayout blah blah android:gravity="center"></LinearLayout>
```

if this doesn't work try this:

```
<LinearLayout blah blah android:layout_gravity="center"></LinearLayout>
```

its definitely a good idea to know the difference, but I'm not going to look it up for you.